# Check if Firebase invite led to the Play Store

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, firebase-invites

When using Firebase invites and accessing the dynamic links at the startup of the app on Android, is there a way to know whether the user just installed the app thanks to the invite or whether it was already installed?

Many thanks,

Borja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Thanks to Catalin Morosan for the answer

It turns out that you can find this out using method `AppInviteReferral.isOpenedFromPlayStore(result.getInvitationIntent())`. In the activity that runs when you click on the invitation:

```
// Create an auto-managed GoogleApiClient with access to App Invites.
mGoogleApiClientInvite = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addApi(AppInvite.API)
        .enableAutoManage(this, this)
        .build();

// Check for App Invite invitations and launch deep-link activity if possible.
// Requires that an Activity is registered in AndroidManifest.xml to handle
// deep-link URLs.
boolean autoLaunchDeepLink = false;
AppInvite.AppInviteApi.getInvitation(mGoogleApiClientInvite, this, autoLaunchDeepLink)
        .setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<AppInviteInvitationResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(AppInviteInvitationResult result) {
                        if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                            // Extract information from the intent
                            Intent intent = result.getInvitationIntent();
                            String invitationId = AppInviteReferral.getInvitationId(intent);
                            boolean alreadyUser = AppInviteReferral.isOpenedFromPlayStore(result.getInvitationIntent());
                            if (alreadyUser) {
                                // Do stuff...
                            } else {
                                // Do other stuff...
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: This does not work. AppInviteReferral.hasReferral() returns true for both situations. I see there is AppInviteReferral.isOpenedFromPlayStore() which should behave as we want it to.

Comment: @CatalinMorosan you are correct I hadn't had a chance to test it until now because my app wasn't on the Play Store. Now it is and your answer works as opposed to hasReferral()

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this Google product form post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/firebase-talk/2STD8eIi61I/8KJqZN7TBAAJ), the Firebase Dynamic Links library will only check for incoming deep links once per app lifetime, meaning you'd need to uninstall and reinstall the app for it to check again. This feeds into the behavior of the [`getInvitation()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/android/gms/appinvite/AppInviteApi#getInvitation(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20android.app.Activity,%20boolean)) method, and it appears you can imply whether the app was previously installed based on the results of this method.

To me, this seems awfully confusing. At [Branch.io](https://branch.io) we do it completely differently: your link data object will always contain an [`is_first_session`](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/deep-link-routing/advanced/android/#branch-provided-data-parameters-in-callback) boolean, which you can programmatically handle in any way you choose.