# Dynamic link automatic Events are not showing on logcat

Tags: xamarin.android, firebase-dynamic-links

What I am trying to accomplish is to use dynamic link to open my app(Xamarin Android) using Firebase Dynamic link. These dynamic link I have created through Firebase console. There are some events related to Dynamic link as listed below

1.dynamic_link_first_open

2.dynamic_link_app_open

3.dynamic_link_app_update

There are few questions I have come across while implementing Dynamic link as listed below:
1.Are above all events compatible with Android app?
2.When I went through the logcat, I didn’t find any event  getting logged. So, what can the reason be for now showing above events in logcat?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that these events are reported remotely in the online Firebase Analytics tool, not inside the app itself.

Assuming you just want to control your app experience based on these lifecycle stages, check out my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39808749/check-if-firebase-invite-led-to-the-play-store/39834363#39834363) for a workaround.